# Printing string containing ANSI Escape Sequences

Tags: bash

In a bash script I have set a variable named `red` to the result of calling the `tput` command.

```
red="$( tput bold; tput setaf 196 )"
```

I would like to print the exact contents but an finding the task difficult.  For instance, I cannot simply do `echo "@red"` because this only sets the colour environment rather than printing the contents of the variable `red`.

Comment: Do you mean `echo "$red"`? `@red` doesn't do anything special in bash. Also, printing the exact contents of the variable *will* cause the terminal to switch to red (because that's what a terminal prgram does when it sees those escape sequences). Do you mean you want to convert the contents to an alternate representation for printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf %q` to escape the special characters:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$red"
$'\E[1m\E[38;5;196m'
```

Or `cat -v`:

```
$ echo "$red" | cat -v
^[[1m^[[38;5;196m
```

Comment: I do get `$'\E[1m\E[38;5;196m'` but want to adapt this to remove the start `$` and the enclosing `'`.